# How to get ID instead of entity object from a relation field in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to fetch a related entity's ID from current entity's field. How can I do this?

For example, assume I have two entity classes. `Company` and `Employee`. `Company` has `Employee` set. With Core Data, I will do this to get that from company.

```
TTCompany* company = <get company>
TTEmployee* employee = [[company employees] anyObject];
id employeeID = employee.objectID;
```

What I want to get is just only the `employeeID`. I don't need to load the employee object now, because I will resolve them later if required. And obviously, current company object has the employee's ID. I think there's a way to get this without fetching any data.

Is there any better way to get ID without loading the object?

Comment: No, there is no better way. Core Data is an object graph management database, you can not get only one 'arribute' like in SQL. You should fetch the appropriate TTEmployee objects, or get the employees related to a company as a set or array. 

Note, that [[company employees] anyObject] results an NSArray with the related TTEmployee* objects, not an TTEmployee* object.

Comment: You can ask for specific attributes while building fetch with setPropertiesToFetch:, and the result will be a set of NSDictionary each containing your properties. But for retrieving the objectID only, I would go for NSManagedObjectIDResultType

Comment: What I meant was the company object already has ID to an employee object. The relation it self an ID. So I just want to get the ID value which is already a part of the company object. Anyway I think I have some wrong assumption. I'll update question as I confirm my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If they have relationship, rather than going from Company to employee, you can build a fetch request on Employee that has a given company.
Then before execute set the return result type a NSManagedObjectID.

I wrote this without testing, and a little bit verbose to make the concept more clear.

```
NSFetchRequest *myFetchRequest =[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
myFetchRequest.entity=<your employee description>;
myFetchRequest.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(company==%@)",yourCompany];
myFetchRequest.setResultType=NSManagedObjectIDResultType;

// execute fetch and the rest....
```